# Making Multiple Background Images Appear in CSS for Blockquotes

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to create a blockquote designation in CSS but only one element I'm trying to have appear in the quotes section(homepage-quotation-marks-1.png) actually shows up. If anyone could help me get the other three elements (bg-quote3a.png/bg-quote3b.png/homepage-quotation-marks-2.png) to become visible, that'd be great. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake I'm overlooking. Thanks!

```
<head>
<style>
background: url(http://royalelectric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/homepage-quotation-marks-1.png) no-repeat left top,
            url(http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bg-quote3a.png) no-repeat center top,
            url(http://royalelectric.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bg-quote3b.png) no-repeat center bottom,
            url(http://royalelectric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/homepage-quotation-marks-2.png) no-repeat right bottom,
color: #a5a4a4;
font-style: italic;
padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%; 
margin: 3% 3% 3% 3%; 
background-color: rgba(202, 206, 239, 1) ;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<blockquote>
<h1>Header!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Vivamus ultricies tellus orci, feugiat viverra diam tristique eu. Pellentesque in nisl suscipit, condimentum elit sit amet, volutpat eros.</p>
</blockquote>
</body>
```

Comment: can u post the actual image urls so that we can see where the mistake is

Comment: If you want multiple-backgrounds they should be **comma separated** and not **semi-colon separated**.

Comment: Just put up the real URLs and made the comma changes, but no change there.

Comment: I see you missed the semicolon after your last `url()`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much, I knew it was something stupid I was overlooking. Appreciate the help!